# Implementing g+1 and google circle in LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

In my new game I am trying to have the g+1 and google Plus circles. I do find lot of tutorial in Android but not even one with Android + LibGdx for my purpose.

The main problem I face in having the g+1 button is the annotation bubble. The bubble shows the number of persons who has already +1ed the app. How to get the annotation value ?

Is there is a guide for implementing the g+1 and google circle feature in LibGdx ?

Comment: This may help you: http://blog.supercookie.co.uk/post/76839739954/google-plus-one-button-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally all game engines using Android OpenGL use [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) (or general [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)). This view  like all other views (`EditText`, `Button`, etc) is of type regular Android views. Therefore, you can arrange it
along side other views in regular Andorid layout views (e.g. `LinearLayout`, `RelativeView`).

In your case, you can use `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` to overlay this two views (LibGDX's `SurfaceView` and the Google+1 view).

- **LibGDX view:**

  ```
  View libgdxView = initializeForView(new GameWorld(this), false);
  ```
- **G+1 button:** [Adding a Google +1 button in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843550/adding-a-google-1-button-in-android-app)

So, similar to question below, you can add this G+1 button wherever you like in the screen.

[Can I have Android Views overlayed on top of the libgdx GL surface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687831/can-i-have-android-views-overlayed-on-top-of-the-libgdx-gl-surface)

Comment: Thanks I will try this